# Type conversion mismatch with generic extension method

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I am attempting to hide a whole set of legacy methods behind a single extension method using generics. These legacy methods are all called GetValidXXX and have a similar signature (and yes they should really be **out** not **ref**). The old GetValidXXX need to be kept for backwards compatibility.

```
    public static T GetAttributeValue<T>(this DbElement element, DbAttribute attribute, T defaultValue)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(DbAttribute))
        {
            if (element.GetValidAttribute(attribute, ref result)) return result;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
        {
            if (element.GetValidBool(attribute, ref result)) return result;
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
```

This will not compile because result does not match the type in the specific GetValidXXX signature (return values is success/fail).

```
bool GetValidAttribute(DbAttribute attribute, ref DbAttribute result)
bool GetValidBool(DbAttribute attribute, ref bool result)
etc
```

How can I write this to achieve what I am aiming for i.e. to be able to write code that looks like this:

```
string description = element.GetAttributeValue(DbAttributeInstance.DESC, "unset");
bool isWritable = !element.GetAttributeValue(DbAttributeInstance.READONLY, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `T` for your ref parameters because the compiler cannot always guarantee it will be of those types. You would have to do something like this:

```
public static T GetAttributeValue<T>(this DbElement element, DbAttribute attribute, T defaultValue)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(DbAttribute))
    {
        var dbAttribute = default(DbAttribute);
        if (element.GetValidAttribute(attribute, ref dbAttribute)) return (T)(object)dbAttribute;
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
    {
        var boolResult = default(bool);
        if (element.GetValidBool(attribute, ref boolResult)) return (T)(object)boolResult;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: The double cast was what I needed here.

Answer (score 1):

[`Convert.ChangeType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cytax8kf.aspx) might be useful in your case.

Possible usage:

```
    public static T ConvertTypeOrGetDefault<T>(this object value, T defaultValue)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

It depends on how "hacky" you're willing to be.  You also could consider re-factoring so that you don't have to hide the legacy methods.

Comment: Thanks, the refactoring is my long-term goal. Need thinks not to break in the meantime.